# Is there a way to connect repl.it with data in local drive?

Tags: python-2.7, web, python-standalone

On [repl.it](https://repl.it/Hp12/23), I tried to call the path I know it exists, but it gave me an error.

Code:

```
import os
print os.path.exists('C:\Users\')
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
exited with non-zero status
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your backslashes. See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

```
import os
print os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\')
```

Comment: Same error. I suspect there may be restriction on the path, is it possible? And how can I confirm that?

Comment: `os` is also missing in your example (you have only the word `import`). Did you correct that? This code works fine in repl.it when I attempt to run it.

Comment: Please look at [this](https://repl.it/HqYD) repl. The code works perfectly.